# Use Green's Theorem to prove Green's first identity

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, greens-theorem

The exercise asks

> Use Green's Theorem in the form of equation 13 to prove Green's First Identity:
> $$
> \iint\limits_D f \nabla^2 g \, dA = \oint_C f(\nabla g) \cdot \mathbf{n} \, ds - \iint\limits_D \nabla f \cdot \nabla g \, dA
> $$
> where $D$ and C satisfy the hypotheses of Green’s Theorem and the appropriate partial derivatives of $f$ and $g$ exist and are continuous.

Equation 13 is
$$
\oint_C \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \, ds = \iint\limits_D \text{div} \; \mathbf{F}(x,y) \, dA
$$

One approach I tried was adding the right-most integral to the left side, rewriting $f \nabla^2 g + \nabla f \cdot \nabla g$ as $\nabla \cdot (f \nabla g)$. I did this using the math below:
$$
        f \nabla^2 g + \nabla f \cdot \nabla g = f\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} + f\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2} + f\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial z^2} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \\
        = f\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}  + f\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} + f\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial z^2} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \\
        = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[ f \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \right] + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left[ f \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \right] + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left[ f \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \right] \\
        = \nabla \cdot (f \nabla g)
$$

From here my goal was to show that $ \iint_D \nabla \cdot (f \nabla g) \, dA 
 = \oint_C f(\nabla g) \cdot \mathbf{n} \, ds = \iint_D \text{div} \; f(\nabla g) \, dA$, but then I got stuck here. Is there a way to continue using this approach or is there another, possibly more elegant way that this can be done?

Also, my highest level of math knowledge is just vector calculus (to be more specific, curl and divergence because that's what I'm studying at the moment), so please don't somehow find a way to explain the answer in terms of differential geometry or something, because it's not going to be useful. (This has happened numerous times)

Comment: From your work we have $f \nabla^2 g + \nabla f \cdot \nabla g=\nabla \cdot (f \nabla g)=\text{div} \; f(\nabla g)$, then apply Equation 13

Comment: @RobertZ I haven't justified $\nabla \cdot (f \nabla g) = \text{div} \; f(\nabla g)$ yet

Comment: $\nabla \cdot F = \text{div} \;F$ is the definition of divergence: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Definition_in_coordinates

Comment: @RobertZ Yes but isn't $f(\nabla g)$ a composition rather than a product?

Comment: @ProPoop No. $\big(f(\boldsymbol \nabla g)\big)(\mathbf v)$ is definitely $f(\mathbf v) \times (\boldsymbol \nabla g)(\mathbf v)$ here.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ functions of the two variables $x$ and $y$? Equation 13 is in two variables.

Comment: @kipf Really? This entire time I thought it was a composition!

Comment: @RobertZ Now that I think about it I don’t think it was necessary to treat $f$ and $g$ as three variable functions when expanding the expression.

Comment: Here, it is not necessary to consider the variable $z$. The $d$-dimensional Green's first identity is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities#Green's_first_identity